# Password Database on PHP file

Tags: php, passwords

A quick question for you! This is my first WEB application...
Is it safe leaving the password visible in the PHP file or there is a way to protect/hide it?

Thank you

Davide

Comment: in PHP file Or in your phpmyadmin?

Comment: This question is kind of off topic OP, if you do not want a wave of downvotes coming to your question I'd strongly suggest you posting code of what you have, and what you wish to achieve.

Comment: in the file i have the instruction for connecting to the db: $mysqli = new mysqli( "address IP" , "user", "password", "db_name");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists different situations to store a password, which cannot be handled in the same manner.

1. The worst case for security is, when you need the password **later in cleartext** for another service. From your comment i can see that this is your situation, you need to store the database login credentials. There is not much you can do, but storing the password in a separate include file, and place it somwhere above the root directory.
2. A little better is the case, when your application needs to store a fix **password only for verification**. Then you can store a hash of the password, so even if somebody can read your code, he doesn't know the plaintext password. An example of this case is a protected directory with HTTP-auth.
3. The best case is when you have to store **user passwords**. Then one should absolutely calculate a hash of the password, so that nobody but the user ever knows (or can retrieve) the password. Recommended algorithms are BCrypt, PBKDF2 and SCrypt (see [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)). Never use MD5 or SHA-* because they are too fast and can be brute-forced too easily.

I included the three cases in the answer, because sooner or later surely you will stumble over the other cases as well.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not safe or a good practice to keep the password visible anywhere. Even you/developer should not know the password except the user.

Use hash for encrypting the password and sha256/sha512 is considered  best algorithm for hashing.

Answer (score 0):

No, You must always think about security. If passwords are stored in plain text, what happens if an attacker gains access to your database? He can easily read all of the users’ passwords. That’s why we use a technique called password hashing to prevent attackers from getting user passwords.

Use md5() php function to secure your password .

```
$password = md5($password);
```

Comment: MD5 isn't secure and should be avoided to hash passwords. To hash passwords it's advised to use the password hashing api.

Comment: yes you are right  @CharlotteDunois  this is old and very simple technique and using  md5 for pwd is a bad idea. nt coz of MD5's cryptographic weaknesses, but because it's fast.